# Adding items from 1 array 2 another filtered by dictionary key

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've been trying to logically think about this for a while now and usually I can solve it by writing it out or thinking about it while doing other stuff not associated with programming. However everything I try isn't working. So basically I have 2 `NSArrays`, which are both populated from 2 different plists. Each array is filled with all dictionaries: all have the same keys, and all have the same identical structure, but some may have information associated with a key that some don't. I basically need to check each item in `array1` and see if it exists in `array2` and if it does NOT exist in `array2` then add it to `array1` (or `array3` seeing how you can't mutate an array while iterating through it). I need it to see if it exists by a specific key "`name_key`".

So... In short my end result needs to be an `NSArray` with all objects from both arrays without having objects with duplicate names (from the dictionaries `name_key`).

Below is my actual code that doesn't work.

IN CODE BELOW: `originalWhiskiesListArray` = `array1`
`newWhiskiesListArray` = `array2`
`combinedWhiskiesListArray` = `array3` (because you can't mutate an array while iterating through it.

```
BOOL whiskyExists = YES;
    for (NSDictionary *newWhisky in newWhiskiesListArray) {

        for (NSDictionary *originalWhisky in originalWhiskiesListArray) {
            NSString * newWhiskyNameString = [[newWhisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY] lowercaseString];
            NSString * origWhiskyNameString = [[originalWhisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY] lowercaseString];

           //Compare lowercase strings and if they don't match then add them to the original plist array.
            if ([newWhiskyNameString isEqualToString:origWhiskyNameString]) {
                whiskyExists = YES;
                break;
            } else {
                whiskyExists = NO;
                break;
                //NSLog(@"Whisky names do not match. New Whisky: %@ Old Whisky: %@",[newWhisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY],[originalWhisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY]);
                //doesn't match so add it
                                }
        }
        if (whiskyExists == NO) {
            [combinedWhiskiesListArray addObject:newWhisky];
            NSLog(@"newWhisky added");
            whiskyExists = YES;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can either of the whiskey name strings be nil? If so then this breaks the isEqualToString comparison because you can always message nil which returns NO.

Also I believe that the breaks are wrong. You only need to exit the inner loop in case you encounter a match. If not you have to keep going until the end of the inner loop.

Comment: no none of them will be nil. but they do have some numbers in them if that matters. for example "Macallan 12yr" would be one of the whiskey names.

Comment: Yes, but sill the second break is wrong because it cancels the inner loop at the first element even when it does not match.

Comment: ok I see what your saying. Is this a good way of doing it? looping through the arrays and comparing I mean.

Comment: Well, looping is a good way like you have it now. Sorting the objects by key into a dictionary or using sets would take more lines of code. So I don't think anything could really be gained if the list of items is relatively small. If it is large then I would use CoreData instead.

Comment: That second break inside of the inner loop was the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Large would be when Instruments shows a significant amount of time being spent on the filtering. Probably a few hundred entries.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can just add all the values from each dictionary to an NSMutableSet, which won't add an item if it already exists in the set. You can then convert the set back to an array with the NSSet method allObjects.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work because in the `originalWhiskiesListArray` users save information inside some of the keys for example they can save a rating which is a number between 1-5 and if an item in the array has the same name under the `name_key` but a different rating under the `rating_key` it will look at it as a different object and add it. I think, atleast thats how it works with the `containsObject:` method. I tried to use the `containsObject:` method on my array.